# Sacrificial Anode with exterior buildup (Cathodic Protection Underwater)

Tags: corrosion

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ed5jkbLEOs

A link to a video of an inspection for a group of sacrificial anodes is above. The video is very long but all of the anodes have the same buildup on the exterior surface. Could this buildup prevent the functionality of the sacrificial anode? The anodes appear to be in pristine condition and I wanted to ensure that this was not because of the buildup preventing passage of current.

I am a mechanical engineer, so I have very little knowledge on this subject.

Comment: Yes I think the galvanic corrosion can become contaminated by the insulative electrical property of  contamination.  Is there any zinc plated steel outside of all the  anodes?   Is there any way to agitate this debris to become loose besides a diver?  Consult the experts in this.

Comment: They look to be pristine.  Factor in when they were installed and you can determine a cleaning cycle.  Time for a ROV with a jet pump.  They appear to be mounted on concrete, which seems strange.